# What does "sē" here stand for?

Tags: lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

[image]
[image: Lingua Latina per se Illustrata: Colloquia Personarum]

What does ***sē*** here means? (*Lingua Latina per se Illustrata: Colloquia Personarum*: 19)

"It is not necessary for him to praise himself" seems strange in the context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is impersonal: *se ipsum laudare* = "to praise oneself." In English you could say:

> **One** must not praise **oneself** like that.

English rarely uses the impersonal "one," though, and it can easily sound stilted. Instead of it, you are liable to often find the impersonal "you" like so: It is not right to praise yourself like that. That might create some ambiguity in this case, however. In the Latin, there is no ambiguity here: Fabia is giving a general rule and not only talking about Cornelius specifically.